# Error when coping object from one table to another in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having one class `ShopOrder` with 2 xml mappings that have only different entity name:

```
<class name="...ShopOrder" [...] entity-name="shopOrder">...
<class name="...ShopOrder" [...] entity-name="shopOrderArchival">...
```

What I want to achieve is to read object from table bounded to class with `entity-name = shopOrder` and save it to the other table (`entity-name = shopOrderArchival`). My code looks like that:

```
public void archive(long orderNumber, Model model) {
    final ShopOrder order = shopOrderQueries.getShopOrderByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
    shopOrderQueries.flushAndClearCurrentSession();
    shopOrderRepository.save("shopOrderArchival", order);
}
```

Sadly I get an exception `Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : shopOrder.collectionName`

How can i do it in a proper way?

Full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : shopOrder.orderedLimitedServiceAvailabilities; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : shopOrder.orderedLimitedServiceAvailabilities
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
xxx.terracotta.websessions.ReloadSessionsObjectsFilter.doFilterInternal(ReloadSessionsObjectsFilter.java:55)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.logic.orders.cart.RequestDataFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestDataFilter.java:40)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.util.RequestCacheControlFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestCacheControlFilter.java:44)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.logic.httpfilters.RequestPartnerModeFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestPartnerModeFilter.java:44)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.logic.wc.RequestWcSettingsFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestWcSettingsFilter.java:81)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.logic.configurations.RedirectToEmptyFilter.doFilterInternal(RedirectToEmptyFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.httpfilters.SessionLog.doFilter(SessionLog.java:39)
org.webdroid.catnip.filter.BadInputFilter.doFilter(BadInputFilter.java:398)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.logic.mobile.MobileVersionByDomainFilter.doFilterInternal(MobileVersionByDomainFilter.java:61)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.httpfilters.ThreadFriendlyNameFilter.doFilterInternal(ThreadFriendlyNameFilter.java:42)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
xxx.httpfilters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:133)
```

Hbm mapping (for archival is the same, only change is in entity-name)

```
<class name="xxx.orders.impl.ShopOrder"  table="xxx" discriminator-value="S" entity-name="shopOrder">

    <id name="id" column="id" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <discriminator column="class" type="char"/>

    <property name="operatorSource">
      <column name="operator_source" sql-type="varchar"/>
      <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.OperatorSource</param>
        <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
      </type>
    </property>
    <property name="orderNumber" column="order_number" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="dateCreate" column="date_create" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="orderFinalizeDate" column="order_finalize_date"/>
    <property name="from" column="customer_from"/>
    <property name="partner"/>
    <property name="invoiceNeeded" column="invoice_needed"/>
    <property name="deliveryEqualsHome" column="delivery_equals_home"/>
    <property name="peselNeeded" column="pesel_needed"/>
    <property name="phone"/>
    <property name="phoneType" column="phone_type"/>
    <property name="smsNotify" column="sms_notify"/>
    <property name="instalmentOnlySmallCaseSwitch" column="instalment_only_small_case_switch"/>
    <property name="blockedForUserEdit" column="blocked_for_user_edit"/>
    <property name="tdUrl" column="td_url"/>
    <property name="tdSuccess" column="td_success" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="canceledByUser" column="canceled_by_user"/>
    <property name="pesel"/>
    <property name="visitId" column="visit_id"/>
    <property name="userId" column="user_id"/>
    <property name="sygmaCreditMotionId" column="sygma_credit_motion_id"/>
    <property name="sygmaCreditMotionUpdateAttempts" column="sygma_credit_motion_update_attempts"/>
    <property name="statusCodesThatEmailNotificationWasSend" column="status_codes_that_email_notification_was_send" />
    <property name="statusCodesThatSmsNotificationWasSend" column="status_codes_that_sms_notification_was_send" />
    <property name="reserveAndCollectMode" column="reserve_and_collect_mode"/>
    <property name="ePaymentTransactionId" column="e_payment_transaction_id"/>
    <property name="historicalEPaymentTranactionIds" column="historical_e_payment_tranaction_ids"/>
    <property name="lastUpdateDate" column="last_update_date"/>
    <property name="ePaymentStatusChangeDate" column="e_payment_status_change_date"/>
    <property name="warrantyRegulationsReaded" column="warranty_regulations_readed"/>
    <property name="userInstalmentNumber" column="user_instalment_number"/>
    <property name="paperInvoice" column="paper_invoice"/>
    <property name="proforma" column="proforma"/>

    <component name="abTestsVariables">
        <property name="simpleOrderPath" column="simple_order_path"/>
        <property name="gridDeliveryPricesIncludesItemsPayments" column="grid_delivery_prices_includes_items_payments" />
        <property name="displayServiceCalculator" column="display_service_calculator" />
        <property name="hideInstalmentOptions" column="hide_instalment_options"/>
    </component>

    <component name="aliorData" access="field">
        <property name="status">
            <column name="alior_status" sql-type="varchar"/>
                <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                    <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.AliorStatus</param>
                    <param name="type">12</param>
                </type>
        </property>
        <property name="applicationNumber" column="alior_application_number" />
        <property name="instalmentCodeSequence" column="alior_instalment_code_sequence" />
        <property name="creditApplicationStatusCode" column="alior_credit_application_status_code" />
        <property name="confirmLoanAgreementSend" column="alior_confirm_loan_agreement_send" />
    </component>

    <component name="platnosciData" access="field">
        <property name="status">
            <column name="platnosci_status" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.PlatnosciTransactionsStatus</param>
                <param name="type">12</param>
            </type>
        </property>
        <property name="amount" column="platnosci_amount" />
    </component>

    <property name="confirmationStatus">
        <column name="confirmation_status" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.ConfirmationStatus</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
    </property> 

    <property name="sygmaCreditMotionStatus">
        <column name="sygma_credit_motion_status" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.sygma.SygmaCreditMotionStatus</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
    </property>     

    <property name="state" not-null="true">
        <column name="state" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.ShopOrderState</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
    </property>

    <property name="appVersion" not-null="true">
        <column name="app_version" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.app.AppVersion</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
    </property>

    <property name="sf1Status">
        <column name="sf1_status" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.sf1.Sf1Status</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
    </property>

    <component name="insuranceData">
        <property name="insuranceNumber" column="insurance_number"/>
        <property name="insuranceDamageNumber" column="insurance_damage_number"/>
        <property name="productReturnRequired" column="product_return_required"/>
        <property name="additionalCharge" column="additional_charge"/>
        <property name="insurerPayment" column="insurer_payment"/>
        <property name="customerPayment" column="customer_payment"/>

        <property name="insuranceType">
            <column name="insurance_type" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.euro.InsuranceType</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
        </property>
    </component>

    <component name="googleCookie">
        <property name="utmcsr" not-null="true"/> 
        <property name="utmccn" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="utmcmd" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="utmcct" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="utmctr" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="utmgclid" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="utmx" not-null="false"/>
        <property name="utmxx" not-null="false"/>
        <property name="cookieHeader" column="cookie_header" not-null="true"/>
    </component>

    <component name="transportData">
        <parent name="shopOrder"/>
        <property name="transportDate" column="transport_date"/>
        <property name="actualDeliveryDate" column="actual_delivery_date"/>
        <property name="transportInterval" column="transport_interval"/>
        <property name="transportIntervalIndex" column="transport_interval_index"/>
        <property name="additionalTransportPrice" column="additional_transport_price"/>
        <property name="realTransportInterval" column="real_transport_interval" />
        <property name="realTransportIntervalIndex" column="real_transport_interval_index" />
        <property name="transportCode" column="transport_code" />
        <property name="sellDocumentResponseCode" column="sell_document_response_code"/>

        <property name="deliveryPaymentPriceType">
            <column name="delivery_payment_price_type" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.DeliveryPaymentPriceType</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
        </property>

        <property name="type">
            <column name="transport_data_type" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.TransportDataType</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
        </property>

        <many-to-one 
            name="instalmentOption"
            column="transport_data_instalment_option_id"
            not-null="false"
            cascade="none"
            foreign-key="b24_instalment_option_transport_data_fkey"
            class="xxx.products.impl.InstalmentOption"
        />
    </component>        

    <component name="actionData">
        <property name="actionStateCode" column="action_state_code"/>
        <property name="actionReservationId" column="action_reservation_id"/>
        <property name="actionReservationLabel" column="action_reservation_label"/>
        <property name="actionReservationMessage" column="action_reservation_message"/>
        <property name="actionToRelease" column="action_to_release" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="actionOrderId" column="action_order_id"/>
    </component>        

    <component name="sf1Data">
        <property name="checkCounter" column="check_counter" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="uid" column="uid" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="amount" column="sf1_amount" not-null="true"/>
    </component>

    <component name="abData">
        <property name="abOrderId" column="ab_order_id"/>
        <property name="abErrorCode" column="ab_error_code"/>
        <property name="abErrorDescription" column="ab_error_description"/>
        <property name="abStatusCode" column="ab_status_code"/>
        <property name="abStatusDescription" column="ab_status_description"/>
        <property name="abToRelease" column="ab_to_release" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="abOrderState">
            <column name="ab_order_state" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.AbOrderState</param>
                <param name="type">12</param>
            </type>
        </property>
    </component>

    <many-to-one access="field"
            name="kredytLineData"
            column="kredyt_line_data_id"
            not-null="false"
            cascade="all"
            foreign-key="b24_shop_orders_kredyt_line_data_fk"
            unique="true"
            class="xxx.orders.impl.ShopOrderKredytLineData"
            entity-name="shopOrderKredytLineData"
        />

    <set name="orderedLimitedServiceAvailabilities" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="order_id" foreign-key="b24_order_to_li_se_av_fkey" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="xxx.orders.impl.OrderedLimitedServiceAvailability" entity-name="orderedLimitedServiceAvailability"/>
    </set>

    <list name="orderItems" lazy="true" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="order_id" foreign-key="b24_order_to_item_fkey" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="index" />
        <one-to-many class="xxx.orders.impl.OrderItem" entity-name="orderItem"/>
    </list>

    <list name="orderedSuites" lazy="true" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="order_id" foreign-key="b24_ordered_suite_to_order_fkey" not-null="true"/>
        <list-index column="index" />
        <one-to-many class="xxx.orders.impl.OrderedSuite" entity-name="orderedSuite"/>
    </list>

    <list name="headDeliveryPayments" lazy="true" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="order_id" foreign-key="b24_order_to_delivery_payment_instance_fkey"/>
        <list-index column="index" />
        <one-to-many class="xxx.orders.impl.DeliveryPaymentInstance" entity-name="deliveryPaymentInstance"/>
    </list>

    <set name="smses" cascade="none" inverse="true">
        <key column="shop_order_id" foreign-key="b24_sms_to_shop_order_fkey" not-null="false"/>
        <one-to-many class="xxx.orders.impl.Sms"/>
    </set>

    <set name="euroOrders" cascade="none" inverse="true" order-by="time_stamp">
        <key column="shop_order_id" foreign-key="b24_euro_order_to_shop_order_fkey" not-null="false"/>
        <one-to-many class="xxx.orders.euro.EuroOrder" />
    </set>

    <many-to-one 
        name="ePaymentBank"
        column="e_payment_bank_id"
        not-null="false"
        cascade="none"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_e_payment_bank_fkey"
        class="xxx.banks.EPaymentBank"
    />

    <many-to-one 
        name="frontUser" 
        class="xxx.customers.IFrontUser"
        column="front_user_id"
        cascade="none"
        not-null="true"
        unique="false"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_front_user_fkey"
    />

    <many-to-one
        name="orderInvoice"
        class="xxx.orders.IOrderInvoice"
        column="order_invoice_id"
        cascade="all"
        not-null="true"
        unique="true"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_oinvoice_fkey"
        entity-name="iOrderInvoice"
    />

    <many-to-one
        name="delivery"
        class="xxx.orders.IDelivery"
        column="delivery_id"
        cascade="all"
        not-null="true"
        unique="true"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_delivery_fkey"
        entity-name="iDelivery"
    />

    <many-to-one
        name="payment"
        class="xxx.orders.IPayment"
        column="payment_id"
        cascade="all"
        not-null="true"
        unique="true"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_payment_fkey"
        entity-name="iPayment"
    />

    <many-to-one 
        name="operator" 
        class="xxx.users.IOperator"
        column="operator_id"
        cascade="none"
        not-null="false"
        unique="false"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_operator_fkey"
    />

    <many-to-one
        name="toDepository"
        class="xxx.dictionaries.IDictionaryItem"
        column="to_depository_id"
        cascade="none"
        not-null="false"
        unique="false"
        lazy="false"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_td_di_fkey"
    />

    <many-to-one
        name="holidayPromotionStatus"
        class="xxx.products.impl.HolidayPromotionStatus"
        column="holiday_promotion_status_id"
        not-null="false"
        unique="false"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_hps_fkey"
    />

    <many-to-one 
        name="smsNotificationService"
        class="xxx.orders.impl.OrderedService"
        column="sms_notification_service_id"
        cascade="all"
        not-null="false"
        unique="false"
        foreign-key="b24_order_to_sms_service_fkey"
        entity-name="orderedService"
    />

    <many-to-one 
        name="instalmentOption"
        column="instalment_option_id"
        not-null="false"
        cascade="none"
        foreign-key="b24_instalment_option_shop_order_fkey"
        class="xxx.products.impl.InstalmentOption"
    />

    <many-to-one 
        name="userInstalmentOption"
        column="user_instalment_option_id"
        not-null="false"
        cascade="none"
        foreign-key="b24_user_instalment_option_shop_order_fkey"
        class="xxx.products.impl.InstalmentOption"
    />

    <many-to-one
        name="synchronizedData"
        class="xxx.orders.ShopOrderSynchronizedData"
        column="shop_order_synchronized_data_id"
        cascade="all"
        not-null="true"
        unique="true"
        access="field"
        foreign-key="b24_shop_order_to_euro_order_date_fkey"
        entity-name="shopOrderSynchronizedData"
    />

    <component name="voucherData">
        <many-to-one 
            name="voucher" 
            class="xxx.vouchers.Voucher"
            column="voucher_id"
            cascade="none"
            not-null="false"
            foreign-key="b24_voucher_voucher_to_product_id_fkey"
        />
        <many-to-one 
            name="alias" 
            class="xxx.vouchers.VoucherAlias"
            column="voucher_alias_id"
            cascade="none"
            not-null="false"
            foreign-key="b24_order_to_voucher_alias_id_fkey"
        />
        <property name="discountValueSplit" column="voucher_data_discount_value_split"/>
        <property name="usageUpdated" column="voucher_data_usage_updated"/>

        <property name="deliveryPaymentDiscountType" not-null="true">
            <column name="voucher_delivery_payment_discount_type" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.vouchers.VoucherDeliveryPaymentDiscountType</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
        </property>

    </component>

    <component name="consolidateData" access="field" >
        <many-to-one 
            name="order" 
            class="xxx.orders.impl.ShopOrder"
            column="consolidate_data_order_id"
            cascade="all"
            not-null="false"
            foreign-key="b24_consolidate_order_id_fkey"
            entity-name="shopOrder"
        />
    </component>

    <property name="IPAddress" column="ip_address"/>

    <property name="ecardStatus">
        <column name="ecard_status" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.ECardStatus</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
    </property>

    <property name="ePaymentToErpStatus">
        <column name="e_payment_to_erp_status" sql-type="varchar"/>
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">xxx.orders.impl.EPaymentToErpStatus</param>
                <param name="type">12</param><!-- to jest java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
            </type>
    </property>

    <many-to-one
        name="partnerClient"
        class="xxx.orders.impl.PartnerClient"
        column="partner_client_id"
        cascade="all"
        not-null="false"
        unique="false"
        foreign-key="b24_partner_client_id_fkey"
    />

     <many-to-one
        name="euroPartner"
        class="xxx.users.impl.Partner"
        column="euro_partner_id"
        cascade="none"
        not-null="false"
        unique="false"
        foreign-key="b24_partner_id_fkey"
    />

    <many-to-one
        name="partnerOperator"
        class="xxx.users.IOperator"
        column="partner_operator_id"
        cascade="none"
        not-null="false"
        unique="false"
        foreign-key="b24_partner_operator_id_fkey"
    />

    <one-to-one 
        name="consoleData"
        access="field"
        class="xxx.orders.impl.ShopOrderConsoleData"
        cascade="save-update, delete" 
        lazy="false"
        entity-name="shopOrderConsoleData"
    />

    <one-to-one 
        name="status"
        access="field"
        class="xxx.orders.impl.ShopOrderStatus"
        cascade="save-update, delete" 
        lazy="false"
        entity-name="shopOrderStatus"
    />

</class>
```

Comment: Can you update the questione withe the Class definiton and The complete stack trace of the exception

Comment: You mean hbm class definiton or java?

Comment: If you are not using the annotation show the hbm otherwise show the Java class and your full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like you're replacing the whole reference of a Collection by another. But if "shopOrderArchival" is not null, then you should clear the collection and add all new elements.

Take a look at this: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897783/exception-in-hibernate-dont-change-the-reference-to-a-collection-with-cascade)

Comment: The collection should be also copied to table with suffix ```_archival```